# How android device authentication finger print scanner can be used to generate fingerprint image/ what are the other options?

Tags: java, android, fingerprint

Is it possible to generate an finger print image using the inbuilt finger print scanner available in modern android phones ?

It works fine for unlocking the device, but what are the other things can be done using it? kindly share some awesome things can be done using it for a developer.

i have a `letv le 1s`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Android Fingerprint API, it's only allow to verify current user against user of device.

To get fingerprint image or template, you need to use external fingerprint scanners compatible with Android Platform and with SDK for Android. For instance:

- http://www.dermalog.com/en/products_solutions/fingerprintscanner/
- http://www.futronic-tech.com/product_fs80h.html
- http://www.crossmatch.com/authentication-hardware/